# How do you go about implementing a interpreter(in Haskell) for a simple programming language which is an imperative-style language

Tags: haskell

I have been given with the language semantics and everything i should know.It'd only support few operations and there wouldn't be any concept of Data Types. So i can store anything in a variable and operate on them.

I'd have loops and conditions and function calls and that is it.
I am looking for a start, an example not a theory book. Has anyone ever implemented such a basic language interpreter in Haskell? I am looking for pointers and references.

Thanks !

Comment: That is essentially what the `IO monad` is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm working on one right now as a practice project.

It's a dynamically-typed language, so variables don't have to be declared, but each value has an associated type.  I implemented that using an algebraic data type in Haskell:

```
data Value = BoolValue Bool  -- ^ A Boolean value.
           | NumberValue Double  -- ^ A numeric value.
           | StringValue String  -- ^ A string value.
           -- (several others omitted for simplicity)
```

For execution of programs, I'm using the `StateT` and `ErrorT` monad transformers on top of `IO`:

```
-- | A monad representing a step in an RPL program.
--
-- This type is an instance of 'MonadState', so each action is a function that
-- takes an 'RPLContext' as input and produces a (potentially different)
-- 'RPLContext' as its result.  It is also an instance of 'MonadError', so an
-- action may fail (with 'throwRPLError').  And it is built on the 'IO' monad,
-- so 'RPL' computations can interact with the outside world.
type RPL = StateT RPLContext (ErrorT RPLError IO)

-- | Executes an 'RPL' computation.
-- The monadic result value (of type @a@) is discarded, leaving only the final
-- 'RPLContext'.
runRPL :: RPL a  -- ^ The computation to run
       -> RPLContext  -- ^ The computation's initial context
       -> IO (Either RPLError RPLContext)
       -- ^ An 'IO' action that performs the operation, producing either
       -- a modified context if it succeeds, or an error if it fails.
runRPL a = runErrorT . (execStateT a)
```

The "context" is a combination of a data stack (it's a stack-based language) and an "environment" that holds all the variables that are currently in scope:

```
-- | The monadic state held by an 'RPL' computation.
data RPLContext = RPLContext {
  contextStack :: Stack,  -- ^ The context's data stack.
  contextEnv :: Env  -- ^ The context's environment.
}
```

(Note that `Stack` is just an alias for `[Value]`.)

On top of that foundation, I have a variety of helper functions to do things like manipulate the stack in the current context (held by the `StateT` part of the `RPL` monad).  For example, here are the functions involved in pushing a value onto the stack:

```
-- | Pushes a value onto the stack.
pushValue :: Value -> RPL ()
pushValue x = modifyStack (x:)

-- | Transforms the current stack by a function.
modifyStack :: (Stack -> Stack) -> RPL ()
modifyStack f = do
  stack <- getStack
  putStack $ f stack

-- | Returns the entire current stack.
getStack :: RPL Stack
getStack = fmap contextStack get

-- | Replaces the entire current stack with a new one.
putStack :: Stack -> RPL ()
putStack stack = do
  context <- get
  put $ context { contextStack = stack }
```

`getStack`, `putStack`, and `modifyStack` are modeled after `MonadState`'s `get`, `put`, and `modify` functions, but they operate on just one field of the `RPLContext` record.

All the language's built-in commands are just actions in the `RPL` monad, which build on top of tools like `pushValue`.

For parsing code in my language, I'm using [Parsec](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Parsec).  It's pretty nice.

---

On a separate track, unrelated to my RPL interpreter, you might find "[Write Yourself a Scheme in 48 Hours](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Write_Yourself_a_Scheme_in_48_Hours)" helpful.

Answer (score 5):

I would first encode the entire program in an EDSL.  That EDSL would itself be a monad and resemble IO.  A GADT makes this very easy to encode:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs, KindSignatures #-}

module Interp where

import SomeStuff


data Expr :: * -> * where
    -- Commands
    Print   :: String -> Expr ()
    GetLine :: Expr String

    -- Variables (created on demand)
    GetVar :: Name -> Expr Value
    SetVar :: Name -> Value -> Expr ()

    -- Loop constructs
    While :: Expr Bool -> Expr a -> Expr ()
    For   :: Expr a -> Expr Bool -> Expr b -> Expr c -> Expr ()

    -- Expr is a monad
    Return :: a -> Expr a
    Bind   :: Expr a -> (a -> Expr b) -> Expr b

instance Monad Expr where
    return = Return
    (>>=)  = Bind

runExpr :: Expr a -> StateT Variables IO a
runExpr (Print str) = liftIO (putStrLn str)
runExpr GetLine     = liftIO getLine
runExpr (While p x) =
    fix $ \again -> do
        b <- runExpr p
        when b (runExpr x >> again)
runExpr ...
```

For simple languages you can even do something as simple as this without a dedicated EDSL:

```
parseProgram :: Parser (StateT Variables IO ())
parseProgram = ...
```

It's often forgotten that Haskell takes the notion of functional programming to its conclusion.  Let the parser return the program itself.  Then you just need to runStateT it with a suitable starting state.

Answer (score 2):

One way would be to have your interpreter run in a [StateT](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/transformers/latest/doc/html/Control-Monad-Trans-State-Lazy.html#t%3aStateT) monad, using a [Map](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/containers/latest/doc/html/Data-Map.html) to emulate mutable variables.  Simple example:

```
import Control.Monad.State
import Data.Map (Map)
import qualified Data.Map as Map

type VarName = String
data Value = VInt Int
           | VString String
type InterpreterState = Map VarName Value

type InterpretM = StateT InterpreterState IO

putVar :: VarName -> Value -> InterpretM ()
putVar varname value = modify (Map.insert varname value)

getVar :: VarName -> InterpretM Value
getVar varname = do
    m <- gets (Map.lookup varname)
    case m of
        Just x  -> return x
        Nothing -> error $ "Variable " ++ varname ++ " is undefined"
```

The interpreter would then run in the `InterpretM` monad.  The above accessors give it access to mutable variables (with no support for goodness like closures and lexical scope).

Answer (score 1):

Here is some resource https://github.com/budabudimir/imp_interpreter, this is interpreter for Simple Imperative Language described here http://fsl.cs.illinois.edu/images/0/0d/CS522-Spring-2011-PL-book-imp.pdf